# php os command shell_exec delay & timing code included

Tags: php

I am trying to run a Linux command in php like "wget" but so if the server is downloading a big file does

```
<? $s = shell_exec("wget file"); echo $s ; ?>
```

does echo $s; shows the downloading bar i'm sure it doesn't 
the question is how to run another cmd after this file finishes 
what i am trying to say that when the downloading is finished run an other command like

```
<? 
$s = shell_exec("wget filename.zip"); 
echo $s ;
$c = shell_exec("unzip filename.zip"); 
echo $c; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shell_exec()` function doesn't return until the command is done. If it produces interactive output, like a progress bar, you won't see it until the end.

And if you're running the PHP script through a webserver, the browser doesn't normally show anything until the script is done. [This page](http://www.icemelon.com/tutorials/20/Output_While_Script_is_Still_Running.htm) shows a trick using PHP's output buffering functions to display intermediate results, but I'm not sure how reliable it is; it seems to depends on implementation details of Internet Explorer.

Comment: so how can i echo that the file's finished downloading & the unzip is started .? & thnx for editing

Comment: If you're running this from a browser, nothing gets shown until the entire script is done.